# Why does zsh ignore the PATH entry order?

Tags: shell, path, command, zsh, resolution

I am trying to use a very basic setup pattern here: I have two different installations of a given tool (ocamlc, but that does not really matter). In order to select one tool, I attempt to override the PATH variable by prepending an entry.

```
% where ocamlc     
/home/choeger/ueb/uebb/amsun-integration/Runtime/test_src/../../opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamlc
/home/choeger/.opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamlc
/usr/bin/ocamlc
```

However, the zsh still uses the older entry:

```
% ocamlc -v        
The OCaml compiler, version 4.02.3
Standard library directory: /home/choeger/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml
```

(One can see that it uses the second entry because the library directory is hardcoded to that installation)

Bash behaves as expected:

```
% bash -c "ocamlc -v"
The OCaml compiler, version 4.02.3
Standard library directory: /home/choeger/ueb/uebb/amsun-integration/opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml
```

So why does zsh ignore the first PATH entry although it lists it as first element of `where`?

edit:
In order to verify that zsh does not invoke the same binary, here is another run:

```
% type -a ocamlc
ocamlc is /home/choeger/ueb/uebb/amsun-integration/tests/pendulum/../../opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamlc
ocamlc is /home/choeger/.opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamlc
ocamlc is /usr/bin/ocamlc
% ocamlc -v
The OCaml compiler, version 4.02.3
Standard library directory: /home/choeger/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml
% /home/choeger/ueb/uebb/amsun-integration/tests/pendulum/../../opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamlc -v
The OCaml compiler, version 4.02.3
Standard library directory: /home/choeger/ueb/uebb/amsun-integration/opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml
```

edit2:
Here is the setopt output:

```
% setopt
autocd
autopushd
nobeep
completeinword
correct
extendedglob
extendedhistory
histignorealldups
histignorespace
nohup
interactive
interactivecomments
longlistjobs
monitor
nonomatch
pushdignoredups
shinstdin
zle
%
```

Config is the grml config found [here](http://git.grml.org/?p=grml-etc-core.git;a=blob_plain;f=etc/zsh/zshrc;hb=HEAD) plus some path variables in the .local file.

Answer (score 15):

By default `zsh` hashes locations of commands the first time they are executed. When executing it a second time the hashed path is used. To refresh the hash table run

```
rehash
```

or

```
hash -r
```

This should happen automatically every time you change `PATH` and its main use is, when new executables are added to directories already in `PATH`.

---

**Note**: the following might be overkill for the specific use case. But it also does solve the issue and might be of interest for slightly different use cases.

If you do not care about the (probably negligible) performance hit, you can disable hashing of commands by disabling the `HASH_CMDS` option:

```
setopt nohashcmds
```

While `zsh` will still be using the hash table, it will not automatically add every command. So, unless a command is entered to the hash table by other means, `zsh` will check `PATH` for the command every time.

This might still lead to problems, if the option `CORRECT` is set. As this does set the hash table in order to provide spelling correction, but will not necessarily refresh it when `PATH` changes. In order to refresh the table automatically, you can use the `precmd` hook which is executed each time before the prompt is printed.

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
auto_rehash () {
    rehash
}
add-zsh-hook precmd auto_rehash
```

Comment: That is a nice answer. And indeed `hash` shows that the entry still points  to the old location. Unfortunately the rehash-ing does not change a thing here. Where does rehash get its source? Did I hit a genuine bug here?

Comment: It should get its information from `PATH`. Strange… What version of `zsh` are you using?

Comment: zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: So, I did some more testing and it seems that any changes in `PATH` should automatically lead to using the correct binary according to the new `PATH`, at least with default settings on `zsh` 5.0.6 and 5.2. So this being a bug seems not that likely. Could please post a link to your configuration or at least add the output of `setopt` to your question?

Comment: Added setopt and link to config file.

Comment: I tested the configuration on my system (zsh 5.2) and everything seems to work as it should: when changing `PATH` the new setting is immediately used. Looking through the configuration, it even contains some extra functionality to ensure that `rehash` is done automatically to avoid any problems with correction or completion. Maybe updating to zsh 5.2 will solve the issue, but - as I said - I think it unlikely, I am sorry, but I am out of ideas.

Comment: Mind. Blown. Thanks for this, I thought I was seeing things.

Answer (score 0):

zsh does not skip PATH entries. It does, however, give priority of alias and shell functions. This doesn't apply to your case, because if you had any of those, `where` would have listed this too.

In your case, if the `where` and the `ocamlc` command have been executed in the same shell, and in that order, you can be pretty sure that `ocamlc` executes `/home/choeger/ueb/uebb/amsun-integration/Runtime/test_src/../../opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamlc`. Did you try running Ocam explicitly via this absolute path? I bet you will get the same output.

BTW, `type -a` would give, in general, a bit more detailed information than `where`.

Comment: It must have a different reason. Theoretically, `ocamlc` could query how it was called (via PATH or by abs path), though it is rare that programs are doing this. Try to explicitly cut down the PATH, i.e. `PATH=/home/choeger/ueb/uebb/amsun-integration/tests/pendulum/../../opam/4.02.3/bin  ocamlc -v` .... in this case, zsh doesn't have any other PATH to choose from. If you want to be really sure, write `command ocamlc` instead of just `ocamlc`. The keyword `command` would bypass alias-expansion and shell function definitions.

Comment: command does not change anything, explicitly restricting the path leads to the expected result.

Comment: The difference between `type -a` and `where` is mostly formating. The exception being functions, for which `where` actually prints the function body, while `type -a` just states "is a shell function". So `type -a` would give less detailed information.